# How to get the precision and scale of a numeric field from table structures in an MS Access database?

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

I used the solution of [How to query table structures from an access database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54075828/how-to-query-table-structures-from-an-access-database) to read the structure of all the tables and odbc-Datasources in an Access database with C#.

But now there is a column like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [schema].[Z_PLZ](
    [Z_PLZ_KEY_IKZ] [numeric](9, 0) NOT NULL,
```

I don't know how to read the precision and scale out of the TableDef:

```
GetApp().CurrentDb().TableDefs
```

I got a cField variable of type "Field" (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/field-members-dao)) and tried this:

```
foreach (var item in props)
{
    var prop = item as Property;
    Debug.WriteLine("Name: " + prop.Name + "..." + prop.Value);
}
```

But it throws an exception.

So how can I get the precision and scale from the table definition?

Comment: Are you using an ODBCConnection to open your database? It seems that you are using the DAO libraries instead. With OdbcConnection is just a matter to call GetSchema to retrieve all the infos about your table (precision and scale included)

Comment: This is used out of a VBE-AddIn to read the native access-tables and the odbc-Datasources which are already in the Access database.

Comment: The precision is property _CollatingOrder_. For the scale, I think you will need ADO to read from the schema.

Comment: Related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1630526/2144390). TL;DR: apparently Access DAO does not expose the details of a `Decimal` field much beyond saying that its `Field#Type` is `dbDecimal` (20).

Comment: @Gustav: My proble is also that I dont know how to access the properties. The above code throws an exception...

Comment: @Gord Thompson: I really cant imagine that there is no way in DAO to tell the difference between a double  [numeric](9, 5)  an and long  [numeric](9, 0) ...

Comment: Have in mind, please, that a property can be an array. If so, your code fails. The reason why not all properties may be accessible can be that, to DAO, the Decimal data type has always been a kind of stepchild.

Comment: You seem to be confusing the various numeric types. `Double` and `Decimal` are not the same thing, and neither `Double` nor `Long Integer` have user-defined precision and scale. DAO can differentiate between the three via the `Type` property of the `Field` object, but it apparently does not expose all of the details for a `Decimal` field.

Comment: @Gord Thompson: In my comany [numeric](9, 2) is used for decimal stuff and [numeric](9, 0) for integer (like primery keys and so on). Both are of the type dbDecimal and my question is how to recognice the difference.